# CodeIgniter - Object of class CI_DB_mysqli_result could not be converted to string

Tags: php, codeigniter

I'm currently using codeIgniter. I'm trying to update a password in a database according to the email address. Otherwise I got a problem, I use the following code for update my database, that I found on the CodeIgniter website.

```
$this->db->set('field', 'field+1', FALSE);
$this->db->where('id', 2);
$this->db->update('mytable'); // gives UPDATE mytable SET field = field+1 WHERE id = 2
```

The error message I got is

> Object of class CI_DB_mysqli_result could not be converted to string

I found a lot of topic on internet talking about this kind of problem. However, I didn't find anything adapted in my case. As I read before, I've already try to return the result of my query like this

```
if ($query->num_rows() == 1)
{
    return $query->result();
}
else
    return FALSE;
```

Which didn't change anything as you may have guess. So Hopeing somebody will be able to explain me what happen. Here's my model code. I didn't put the whole code, because I thing it will me enough but ask me if you want the rest.

```
<?php if (!defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');
class Reset_password extends CI_Model
{
    function __construct()
    {
        parent:: __construct();
        $this->load->helper('url');
        $this->load->helper('string');
    }

    function index($email) //function wchich will reset the password in the database;
    {
        $new_password = random_string('alnum', 16);
        //generate random password, already try to remove and put for exemple
        //$new_password = 'lol'; and doesn't work so I suppose this line isn't 
        //the pb
        $this-> db->set('password', md5($new_password), FALSE);
        $this-> db->where('email', $email);
        $this-> db->update('CI_TEST');

        $query = $this->db->get();
    }
}
```

Thanks :)

EDIT: Here's my controller code

```
<?php if (!defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script acess allowed');

class Forget_password extends CI_Controller
{
    function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
        $this->load->helper(array('form'));
        $this->load->model('Reset_password');
        $this->load->library('email');
    }

    function index()
    {
        $this->load->library('form_validation');
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('email', 'Email', 'trim|required|valid_email|callback_email_check', 'Error: please provide a valide email adresse');

        if ($this->form_validation->run() == FALSE)
        {
            $this->load->view('Forget_password');
        }
        else
        {
           //loading
        }
    }

    function email_check($email)
    {
        $this-> db->select('email');
        $this-> db->from('CI_TEST');
        $this-> db->where('email', $email);
        $this-> db->limit(1);

        $query = $this-> db->get();

        if ($query->num_rows() == 1)
        {           
            $this->Reset_password->index($query);
            return (TRUE);
        }
        else
        {
            echo 'Error: The email you provided doesn\'t exist in the database';
            return (FALSE);
        }
    }
}
?>
```

Comment: In your view/controller, are you trying to `echo $query`? Secondly, an Update won't return anything other than a true/false, you'll have to re-select the rows you want 'returned' whereas here I think here, you are updating & attempting to return a set of rows that were affected.

Comment: try var_dump($query) see what are results

Comment: @MackieeE Hello, no but I edited my original post and add my controller code if you want

Comment: AND also var_dump($this->Reset_password->index($query));

Comment: @AnmolRaghuvanshi var_dump($query) displayed "bool(false)"
and var_dump($this->Reset_password->index($query)) displayed "NULL"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You currently have fetched a result set, you'll need to then use `result()` or `row()` to collect the results into an formatted object (Or an array if you choose `result_array()`). `CI_DB_mysqli_result` is a class wrapper than encases your results, but not yet have you pulled out the data contained *within* it.

```
$this->db->select('email');
$this->db->from('CI_TEST');
$this->db->where('email', $email);
$this->db->limit(1);

$query = $this->db->get();

if ($query->num_rows() == 1)
{           
    //Use row() to get a single result
    $row = $query->row();

    //$row will now have if you printed the contents:
    //print_r( $row );
    //stdClass Object ( [email] => example@gmail.com )

    //Pass $query->email directly to reset_password
    $this->Reset_password->index( $row->email );
    return true;
}
```

Comment: It seem that the message has disappear ! :D                                                     
I didn't use following line                                                                                     
"stdClass Object ([email] => example@gmail.com)"                                         
But can you explain me what happen ?

Comment: @S7_0 The `stdClass Object ([email] => example@gmail.com)` was just an example of what the contents of what `$row` would be if you did `print_r( $row )`, I'll edit this :)