# Unable to retrieve status count after passing Mysql query

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

Currently I'm using CodeIgniter to retrieve my data in a particular timeframe. All these entries have a status. I am trying to get a count of all the data that are present in the particular time frame. Currently this is my model class where I have the following entry to return all the entries in a particular date range:

```
public function get_records($st_date,$end_date){
        $this->db->select('*');
        $this->db->from('crm_listings');
        $this->db->where('cast(added_date as date) BETWEEN "' . $st_date . '" AND "' . $end_date . '" AND status= "D"');
        
        return $this->db->count_all_results();
     }
```

And my controller class:

```
<?php if ( ! defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
ini_set('display_startup_errors', 1);
error_reporting(E_ALL);
   class Testcontroller extends CI_Controller
   {  
      public function index() 
      { 
      $this->load->view('crm/test');      
       }

function fetch_status(){
            $output ='';
            $startDate = '';
            $endDate = '';
            $this->load->model('crm/user_model');
  
            if($this->input->post('startDate')){
              $startDate = $this->input->post('startDate');
            }
            if($this->input->post('endDate')){
               $endDate = $this->input->post('endDate');
             }
            $data = $this->user_model->get_records($startDate,$endDate);
            
            $output .= '
              <div class="table-responsive">
                 <table class="table table-bordered table-striped">
                    <tr>
                    <th>Draft</th>
                    </tr>
              ';
           if($data->num_rows() > 0)
           {
            $output .= '
               <tr>
                  <td>'.$data.'</td>
               </tr>
            ';
            }
           else
           {
              $output .= '<tr>
                 <td colspan="7">No Data Found</td>
                 </tr>';
           }
           $output .= '</table>';
           echo $output;
           }
}     
?>
```

So as of now when I comment everything in my controller class after $data and just make a statement `echo $data;` I get the output I want. But when I'm wrapping it around `<td>'.$data.'</td>`, it doesn't give an output.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Edit your function at line <strike>echo $this->db->count_all_results();</strike>

```
function get_records($st_date,$end_date){
echo $this->db->count_all_results();// change this code
// to
return $this->db->get();
}
```

for make sure there is any data, try to `print_r($data)` after you call that method/function

```
$data = $this->user_model->get_records($startDate,$endDate);
print_r($data) // check data
```

Comment: I did this and it gave me a Object of class CI_DB_mysqli_result could not be converted to string error. and with print_r I got the following CI_DB_mysqli_result Object ( [conn_id] => mysqli Object ( [affected_rows] => 48 ...

Comment: for error try [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32716414/codeigniter-object-of-class-ci-db-mysqli-result-could-not-be-converted-to-stri) solution

Comment: @JayVijayModi, so you have the result, then convert your object `$data` with `$data->result()`

Comment: @shevanto, so I have to do <td>'.$data->result().'</td> ?

Comment: @JayVijayModi, if you want to get count , just do `$data->num_rows()`

Comment: Hey @shevanto, thanks it worked. Could you also check out https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69460762/grouping-multiple-mysql-statements-to-fetch-count-of-multiple-statuses