# Grouping multiple Mysql statements to fetch count of multiple statuses

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

Currently I'm using Mysql and CodeIgniter to fetch my entries from my database in a particular timeframe. Each entry has a status in the database of either D,N,Y. Now to display this data I have a different statement for each of the statuses which I want to group into 1 statement.

Model Class:

```
public function get_records_draft($st_date,$end_date){
        $this->db->select('*');
        $this->db->from('crm_listings');
        $this->db->where('cast(added_date as date) BETWEEN "' . $st_date . '" AND "' . $end_date . '" AND status= "D"');

         return $this->db->get();
     }

     public function get_records_unpublish($st_date,$end_date){
        $this->db->select('*');
        $this->db->from('crm_listings');
        $this->db->where('cast(added_date as date) BETWEEN "' . $st_date . '" AND "' . $end_date . '" AND status= "N"');

        return $this->db->get();
     }

     public function get_records_publish($st_date,$end_date){
        $this->db->select('*');
        $this->db->from('crm_listings');
        $this->db->where('cast(added_date as date) BETWEEN "' . $st_date . '" AND "' . $end_date . '" AND status= "Y"');

        return $this->db->get();
     }
```

And my controller class where I'm getting this data and displaying it in a form of a table:

```
$data = $this->user_model->get_records_draft($startDate,$endDate);
$data1 = $this->user_model->get_records_unpublish($startDate,$endDate);
$data2 = $this->user_model->get_records_publish($startDate,$endDate);

$output .= '
              <div class="table-responsive">
                 <table class="table table-bordered table-striped">
                    <tr>
                    <th>Draft</th>
                    <th>Unpublish</th>
                    <th>Publish</th>
                    </tr>
              ';
           if($data->num_rows() > 0)
           {
            $output .= '
               <tr>
               <td>'.$data->num_rows().'</td>
               <td>'.$data1->num_rows().'</td>
               <td>'.$data2->num_rows().'</td>
               </tr>
            ';
            
           }
           else
           {
              $output .= '<tr>
                 <td colspan="5">No Data Found</td>
                 </tr>';
           }
           $output .= '</table>';
           echo $output;
```

And this is the AJAX request in my view class:

```
$('#alertbox').click(function(){
            var startDate = $('#startDate').val();
            var endDate = $('#endDate').val();
            // var status = $('#status').val();
            if(startDate != '' && endDate != '' ){
            $.ajax({
                url:"<?php echo base_url(); ?>testcontroller/fetch_status",
                method:"POST",
                data:{startDate:startDate, endDate:endDate},
                success:function(data){
                    $('#result').html(data)
                }
            })
            }else{
                alert("Please enter a date");
            }
        })
```

My question is that is there anyway to group all these into 1 method that'll classify them all in thier particular heading in my controller class.

I have tried using the following query in phpmyadmin which gives me my correct output, but I don't know how do I execute the same thing in my model and controller class:

```
SELECT COUNT(status) FROM `crm_listings` WHERE added_date BETWEEN '2021-09-23' AND '2021-09-29' GROUP BY status
```

Comment: I have encounter similiar problem like this and the best method I'm trying is using `db->query` and create query to get one line result with all sum data

Comment: @adam I want it to be shown systematically so I have created the `<table>` tag in my controller class. But I dont think I can display it how I want to by using the query method

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `CASE` statement instead of multiple queries

Model:

```
public function summary($st_date,$end_date){
      $this->db->select("
         SUM(CASE WHEN status = 'D' THEN 1 END) AS draft,
         SUM(CASE WHEN status = 'N' THEN 1 END) AS unpublish,
         SUM(CASE WHEN status = 'Y' THEN 1 END) AS publish"
      );
      $this->db->where('added_date >=', $st_date);
      $this->db->where('added_date <=', $end_date);
      return $this->db->get('crm_listings');
 }
```

View:

Do not make HTML in the controller because it's a bad practice in MVC. Use `foreach` loop in view file to show values
Read more about from [CI Views](https://codeigniter.com/userguide3/general/views.html#creating-loops)

```
<div class="table-responsive">
    <table class="table table-bordered table-striped">
        <tr>
           <th>Draft</th>
           <th>Unpublish</th>
           <th>Publish</th>
         </tr>
    <?php      
       if(isset($data) && count($data) > 0){
          foreach($data as $row ){ ?>
           <tr>
           <td><?= $row->draft ?></td>
           <td><?= $row->unpublish ?></td>
           <td><?= $row->publish ?></td>
           </tr>
       <?php } //Foreach end here

          } else { ?>
          <tr>
             <td colspan="5">No Data Found</td>
          </tr>
       <?php } ?>
      </table>
```

Read more about [MySQL Case Statement](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/case.html)

Comment: This statement works in phpmyadmin, but when I try it on my page it doesn't bring up anything and shows this in console Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 500 (Internal Server Error)

Comment: @JJM50 please share the full error message

Comment: The thing is I dont get any error message, It's just that nothing pops up in my webpage and I only get this 1 message in my console

Comment: @JJM50 without error detail how can I help you? BTW are you using AJAX request?

Comment: Yes it is an AJAX request. Also I've tried adding`ini_set('display_errors', 1);
ini_set('display_startup_errors', 1);
error_reporting(E_ALL);` on top of my controller class, but it doesn't show any errors. I've added the AJAX request in the question for reference

Comment: @JJM50 then the error will show in the network tab of your browser and you should use Jquery to populate data instead of rendering in the controller

Comment: Oh okay. So the error its showing in the network tab is  Call to a member function result() on array

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/237875/discussion-between-danish-ali-and-jjm50).

Comment: Hey, could you kindly check out https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69514573/table-data-not-showing-correctly-in-codeigniter-table

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
Your models
    public function summary($st_date,$end_date){
            $this->db->select("
            SUM(CASE WHEN status = 'D' THEN 1 END) AS Draft,
            SUM(CASE WHEN status = 'N'  THEN 1 END) AS Unpublish,
            SUM(CASE WHEN status = 'Y' THEN 1 END) AS Publish,
            "
            );
            $this->db->from('crm_listings');
            $this->db->where('cast(added_date as date) BETWEEN "' . $st_date . '" AND "' . $end_date');
    
            return $this->db->get();
         }
```

controllers

```
....
$data = $this->user_model->summary($startDate,$endDate)->result();

echo $data->Draft;
echo $data->Unpublish;
echo $data->Publish;
```

Comment: Tried this and there is no output shown. It brings up this in the console Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 500 (Internal Server Error)

Comment: @JJM50 check your database connection

Comment: have you setting environment to development?

Comment: Danish Ali, yeah thats right, i forgot write that,,,, try again @JJM50

Comment: Hey could you check out https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69517157/table-count-data-not-showing-up-in-view-class