# Mysql statement not working in CodeIgniter Model class

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

Currently I'm trying to retrieve all the entries from my data that are within a particular timeframe. To do this I have a method in my model class with the following statement:

```
public function get_records_all($st_date,$end_date){
        $sql = SELECT
            *
            FROM `crm_listings`  
            WHERE added_date BETWEEN '" . $st_date . "' AND '".$end_date."'
            ORDER BY `added_date` DESC;
            $response = $this->db->query($sql);
            echo $response;
     }
```

And in my controller class I'm using the following statement to show the output:

```
function fetch_status(){
            $startDate = '';
            $endDate = '';
            $this->load->model('crm/user_model');
  
            if($this->input->post('startDate')){
              $startDate = $this->input->post('startDate');
            }
            if($this->input->post('endDate')){
               $endDate = $this->input->post('endDate');
             }

             $data_all = $this->user_model->get_records_all($startDate,$endDate);
}
```

But this gives me the following error:

[image]

Comment: `echo $response;` is expecting to just echo a string, your response won't be one.  I think you want to return the response instead `return $response;`.

Comment: @NigelRen Okay so I changed it to return $response and added a echo $data_all in my controller class, but I'm still getting the same error

Comment: @JayModi why are you using raw query when CI has query builder?

Comment: Why are the contents of our SQL variable not in quotations?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

> CodeIgniter gives you access to a Query Builder class. This pattern
> allows information to be retrieved, inserted, and updated in your
> database with minimal scripting. In some cases, only one or two lines
> of code are necessary to perform a database action. CodeIgniter does
> not require that each database table be its own class file. It instead
> provides a more simplified interface.

```
public function get_records_all($st_date,$end_date){  
 $this->db->where('added_date >=', $st_date);
 $this->db->where('added_date <=', $end_date);
 $this->db->order_by('added_date', 'DESC');
 return $this->get('crm_listings')->result();
}
```

For more use this link [CI Query Builder CLass](https://codeigniter.com/userguide3/database/query_builder.html)

Comment: Alright got it. I have 1 more question regarding this if you could kindly check it out https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69460762/grouping-multiple-mysql-statements-to-fetch-count-of-multiple-statuses

Answer (score 0):

if you insist using `db->query` change your `get_records_all()` response to `return $response;` then you can use `$data_all` as and object like this

```
foreach($data_all as $data) {
  echo $data->some_field;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You forgot to add `->result()` after `$this->db->query($sql)` like:

```
$response = $this->db->query($sql)->result();
```

However you can also use Query Builder like

```
public function get_records_all($st_date,$end_date){

     return $this->db->where('added_date >=', $st_date)
             ->where('added_date <=', $end_date);
             ->order_by('added_date', 'DESC');
             ->get('crm_listings')
             ->result();
}
```